# Add simple validate to form file upload in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have an AngularJS form whose contents are sent to a nodemailer backend. This works just fine, using the following directive to add a file upload component to the form:

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
        });
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

However, I need to add validation to this so that the Submit button is disabled until a file has been chosen. I'm presuming the form would look something like this:

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <!-- FILE UPLOAD -->
  <input type="file" file-model="email.attachment" name="attachment" 
  class="form-control" accept="application/pdf, application/msword, text/plain" />
  <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
  <button  type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-primary' 
  ng-disabled = 'userForm.$invalid' value = 'Send' 
  ng-click = 'uploadFile()'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

I understand that the standard 'required' does not work with the file model, and I can find no examples of the correct procedure. 
How should I modify the directive to implement validation?

Comment: userForm.$invalid will work when form getting submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $rootScope for that :

In your main controller :

$rootScope.fileUploaded = false;

```
 .directive('fileModel', ['$parse','$rootScope', function ($parse,$rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
          if(element[0].files[0]){
          $rootScope.fileUploaded = true;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

In your view :

```
    <div class='form-group'>
  <!-- FILE UPLOAD -->
  <input type="file" file-model="email.attachment" name="attachment" 
  class="form-control" accept="application/pdf, application/msword, text/plain" />
  <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
  <button  type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-primary' 
  ng-disabled = '!fileUploaded' value = 'Send' 
  ng-click = 'uploadFile()'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well this got me on the right track, thanks; I had to do this inside the directive to get it to work:  
                    if(element[0].files[0]){
                      scope.$root.fileUploaded = true;
                    }

Comment: That said, there's much opinion out there against using $rootScope in this kind of scenario, but the alternatives seem to be quite complex.

Comment: Yes but for this you have to complacently aware about it :)