# Upload files with Angular for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angular

I'm trying to upload a file using Angular (currently Angular 4).
But I'm unable to send it correctly.  The best I can do is sending the file as a raw content (available in `$_POST` as some binary mess like this: )

> ëPNG\r\n
>       \x1A\n
>       \x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00©\x00\x00\x008\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00Nâ2\x1F\x00\x00\n
>       óiCCPICC

What I want is the file to be uploaded and available in `$_FILES` variable in PHP.

Currently, I'm using this code in Angular

```
let picture = event.target.files[0];
let content = new FormData();
content.append('picture', picture, picture.name);
let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': this.user.token,
    'Content-Type': picture.type});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
this.http.post(Config.API_URL + `/user/profile/update/`, value, options).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Currently, PHP code is just a `var_dump($_FILES);`

I think my problem may be related to the way Angular transforms the request.
I know there war a *transformRequest* option in AngularJS but I can't find how it works with Angular 4.

Do you have any suggestion on how I can make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479053/add-simple-validate-to-form-file-upload-in-angularjs/40479124#40479124

Comment: Please see angular2 file uploading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985347/how-to-upload-file-in-angular2/40595005#40595005

Comment: Yesssss! Removing `Content-Type` in header and renaming `picture` by `file` in _FormData_ make the upload work!  Thanks a lot.  But I don't really understand why such a small modification can lead to the file not being present in `$_FILES`.